# Cypher: Limiting the number of returned links for a selection of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am failing at an apparently simple query.

Algo:

1. Sort nodes by some value (desc):

   ```
   MATCH (n) WHERE has(n.II_VAL) WITH n, n.II_VAL as ShInflInd order by ShInflInd desc
   ```
2. For each node, return its direct neighbors (ordered by a second value):

   ```
   MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) with n, m, m.VALUE as SubsOpRev order by SubsOpRev desc
   ```

The challenge is to return the top 100 n nodes and for each of them only 10 relations r (if possible in a single row).

**EDIT:**

Sorry for being so unspecific that people understood me wrong.

In detail, the following query gives me the top nodes, sorted:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.II_VAL)
WITH n, n.`II_VAL` AS ShInflInd ORDER BY ShInflInd DESC
RETURN n.NAME LIMIT 100;

+--------------------------------------+
| n.NAME                               |
+--------------------------------------+
| "PUBLIC"                             |
| "BARCLAYS PLC"                       |
```

Now I can add the sub-query to this which adds the links:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.II_VAL)
WITH n, n.`II_VAL` AS ShInflInd ORDER BY ShInflInd DESC LIMIT 100
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE HAS(m.VALUE)
WITH r, n, m, m.VALUE AS SubsOpRev
RETURN n.NAME, r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m.NAME, SubsOpRev LIMIT 10;

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| n.NAME   | r.WEIGHT_MERGED    | m.NAME                                     | SubsOpRev |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "PUBLIC" | 0.66               | "VBS MUTUAL BANK"                          | 2630      |
| "PUBLIC" | 0.2923             | "STRATCORP LIMITED"                        | 10842     |
```

Now what I would like, is that after returning 10 links for "PUBLIC" (possibly sorted by r.WEIGHT_MERGED or SubsOpRev) the query returns the second node ("BARCLAYS PLC") and its 10 links, etc.

I have tried:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.II_VAL)
WITH n, n.`II_VAL` AS ShInflInd ORDER BY ShInflInd DESC
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE HAS(m.VALUE)
WITH r, n, m, m.VALUE AS SubsOpRev
RETURN collect([n.NAME, r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m.NAME, SubsOpRev])[0..10];
```

Resulting in:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| collect([n.NAME, r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m.NAME, SubsOpRev])[0..3]                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [["PUBLIC",0.66,"VBS MUTUAL BANK",2630],["PUBLIC",0.2923,"STRATCORP LIMITED",10842], ...
```

which means I am still stuck with "PUBLIC".

Modifying the query a little makes things worse, as it returns totally different data:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.II_VAL)
WITH n, n.`II_VAL` AS ShInflInd ORDER BY ShInflInd DESC
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE HAS(m.VALUE)
WITH r, n, m, m.VALUE AS SubsOpRev
RETURN n.NAME, collect([r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m.NAME, SubsOpRev])[0..10] LIMIT 3;

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| n.NAME                | collect([r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m.NAME, SubsOpRev])[0..10] |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "RS-INVEST AS"        | [[0.5,"VERUCO EIENDOM AS",100]]                      |
| "DBM"                 | [[0.1435,"CHELYABINSKOBLGAZ",6752]]                  |
```

Ideally, the query should yield something like

```
| [["PUBLIC",0.66,"VBS MUTUAL BANK",2630],["PUBLIC",0.2923,"STRATCORP LIMITED",10842], ... |
| [["BARCLAYS PLC",x,"XYZ",y], ... |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to limit and then continue with your query. To provide a reproducible example, let's switch to the movie dataset that ships with Neo4j. Let's say you want to grab the 3 oldest movies in the database and then the 2 oldest actors in each of those movies.

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH m ORDER BY m.released LIMIT 3
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WITH m, p ORDER BY p.born
WITH m, COLLECT(p.name)[0..2] AS oldest
RETURN m.title, oldest;
```

This yields:

```
   | m.title                         | oldest                              
---+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 1 | Something's Gotta Give          | ['Jack Nicholson', 'Diane Keaton']
 2 | Top Gun                         | ['Tom Skerritt', 'Kelly McGillis']
 3 | One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest | ['Jack Nicholson', 'Danny DeVito']
```

So you'll want something like this:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.II_VAL)
WITH n ORDER BY n.II_VAL DESC LIMIT 100
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE HAS(m.VALUE)
WITH n, r, m ORDER BY m.VALUE DESC
RETURN n.NAME, COLLECT([r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m.NAME, m.VALUE])[0..10];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks. With the following small addition, I get the final list sorted by n.II_VAL again: "... WITH n, n.II_VAL AS ii, r, m ORDER BY m.VALUE DESC RETURN n.NAME, ii, COLLECT([r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m.NAME, m.VALUE])[0..2] ORDER BY ii DESC;"

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe what the problem is?

The big problem seems to be that you're not finishing your queries with a `RETURN`.  `WITH` is used for intermediate passing of data.  Also, you don't actually need to pull out the value to sort on it.  You can do this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE has(n.II_VAL)
RETURN n ORDER BY n.II_VAL DESC LIMIT 100
```

For your second query:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
RETURN n, m ORDER BY m.VALUE DESC LIMIT 100
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot the `LIMIT`

Comment: The query snippets were only meant as illustration. Please see the edits to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of nodes to 100:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE has(n.II_VAL)
WITH n, n.II_VAL AS ShInflInd
ORDER BY ShInflInd DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

You can collect all `SubsOpRev` and then `RETURN` a slice of your collection. Something along this line (I assume the `SubsOpRev` is what you want):

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WITH n, m.VALUE AS SubsOpRev 
ORDER BY SubsOpRev DESC
RETURN n, collect(DISTINCT SubsOpRev)[1..10]
```

This will give you one node `n` per row and a slice of the list of all collected `SubsOpRev`.

Comment: I need to combine the two queries. Please see the edits to my original post.

Comment: You can combine them. Concerning your edits: You have to `ORDER` first and then `collect()` only the relationship or the value you want to return. If you want to have the same order of nodes again, you might want to sort again in your `RETURN`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to add a sub-query (retrieving 10 links) to each node I get from the first sorted search. I don't know how to combine the queries in a non-trivial way...

Answer (score 0):

To get the top 100 nodes based on your first query, you have to add a `RETURN` clause and a `LIMIT` one after the order:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE has(n.II_VAL) 
RETURN n, n.II_VAL as ShInflInd 
order by ShInflInd desc 
LIMIT 100
```

For the second one, you have to do two queries, and implement the Foreach logic on your client side. Because You can't limit to 100 for the first one, and then get 10 related node for each node you got in the same query.

Comment: I didn't manage with looping. Please see the edits to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that you want two sets of results returned in one query.  To do that, I think the best thing to do would be to `collect` in the `WITH` which will give you just one row, and then `RETURN` that value along with a `collect` of the other data.  Something like:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.II_VAL)
WITH collect([n, n.`II_VAL`])[0..100] AS set1 ORDER BY n.`II_VAL` DESC
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE HAS(m.VALUE)
RETURN set1, collect([n.NAME, r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m.NAME])[1..10] ORDER BY r.WEIGHT_MERGED
```

I threw in the `ORDER BY r.WEIGHT_MERGED` as as example of how you can sort by a value again.

If you want your data a bit more structured you can also collect object maps instead of arrays like this:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.II_VAL)
WITH collect({n: n, II_VAL: n.`II_VAL`})[0..100] AS set1 ORDER BY n.`II_VAL` DESC
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE HAS(m.VALUE)
RETURN set1, collect({n_name: n.NAME, weight_merged: r.WEIGHT_MERGED, m_name: m.NAME})[1..10] ORDER BY r.WEIGHT_MERGED
```

Comment: OK, close:) However, the query doesn't know of "n" ("n not defined") in the second row (ORDER BY n.`II_VAL`). If I add it after the "WITH" (WITH n, collect({n...) I loose the original sorting by  n.`II_VAL`. But the structure of what it returns looks like what I am looking for...

Comment: You're losing your bound `n` by leaving it out of the `WITH` clause; at that point you're just matching on all nodes at line 3.